# RStudio Shiny - file input widget: where is the file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, input, shiny, rstudio, dashboard

I am building a Shiny dashboard using some of the widgets in the link below:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html

If I deploy my app on AWS (Amazon Web Services), and if I let the user insert a .csv file as an input, where is the file stored? Does it disappear when the user closes the browser?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you http://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.